# How to split a object irrespective of its type?

Tags: go

I was just fetching all the system specs using the ghw library. The details is available in https://github.com/jaypipes/ghw/#cpu . I wanted to fetch the cpu cache size. So i need to split whatever object which is returning using the following code which im not able to do.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"strings"

"github.com/jaypipes/ghw"
)

func main() {
    topology, err := ghw.Topology()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error getting topology info: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", topology)

    for _, node := range topology.Nodes {
        fmt.Printf(" %v\n", node)
        for _, cache := range node.Caches {
            info := strings.Split(cache, "\n")
        }
    }
}
```

when i do this im getting the following error.

```
./topology.go:21:25: cannot use cache (type *ghw.MemoryCache) as type string in argument to 
strings.Split
```

So how can split this and use only the required data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `ghw.MemoryCache.SizeBytes` field:

> `ghw.MemoryCache.SizeBytes` is an integer containing the number of bytes the cache can contain

So no splitting necessary:

```
for _, node := range topology.Nodes {
    fmt.Printf(" %v\n", node)
    for _, cache := range node.Caches {
        info := strconv.Itoa(cache.SizeBytes)
    }
}
```